# Using DomPDF to generate table list from database

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation, dompdf

I have the following code for generating HTML content to PDF using DomPDF.and my problem focuses on this line

> `$pdf_content='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD...`

The entire code

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
require_once ('dompdf_config.inc.php');
$pdf_content='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            </head>

            <style type="text/css">                         
                #pdf_header, #pdf_container{ border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; padding:10px; }             
                #pdf_header{ margin:10px auto 0px; border-bottom:none; }                
                table{ width:580px; }               
                #pdf_container{margin:0px auto; }
                .rpt_title{ background:#99CCFF; }                                                           
            </style>

            <body>
            <div id="pdf_header" >
            <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
            <tr id="hdRow">
                <td width="20%"><img src="space_age_header.jpg" style="width:250px" ></td>              
                <td width="30%" align="center">Sample File</td>
                <td width="30%" align="left">Marimuthu<br>User Code : 179865420</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            <div id="pdf_container" >
            <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
            <tr align="center" bgcolor="pink" style="color:#FFF"><td colspan="3"><b>Your Statement Summery</b></td> </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#006" style="color:#FFF"><td colspan="3" align="left">Your Heading.</td></tr>
            </table>
            <table> <tr> <td> Name </td><td> Department</td><td>Total </td><td>Grade </td> </tr>
            <tr> <td> Marimuthu </td><td> Admin</td><td>250 </td><td>A </td> </tr>          
            </div></body></html>'
            ;
            $name = date("Ymd").rand().'.pdf';
            $reportPDF=createPDF(12, $pdf_content, 'activity_Report', $name );
    function createPDF($pdf_userid, $pdf_content, $pdf_For, $filename){

    $path='UsersActivityReports/';
    /*$rndNumber=rand();
    $filename=$pdf_userid.date("Ymd").$rndNumber.'.pdf';*/
    $dompdf=new DOMPDF();
    $dompdf->load_html($pdf_content);
    $dompdf->render();
    $output = $dompdf->output();
    file_put_contents($path.$filename, $output);
    return $filename;       
    }   
    echo '<a href="UsersActivityReports/'.$name.'" > Download </a>';
?>
```

I have extracted the `$pdf_content='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD...` part to another page page.php and modified it to allow generating files from database using a do while loop.

```
<?php 

include("../../Connections/dbConfig.php"); 

$query_record = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `subjects`") or 
die (mysqli_error($link));
$row_record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_record);
$totalRows_record = mysqli_num_rows($query_record);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            </head>

            <style type="text/css">                         
                #pdf_header, #pdf_container{ border: 1px solid #CCCCCC; padding:10px; }             
                #pdf_header{ margin:10px auto 0px; border-bottom:none; }                
                table{ width:580px; }               
                #pdf_container{margin:0px auto; }
                .rpt_title{ background:#99CCFF; }                                                           
            </style>

            <body>
            <div id="pdf_header" >



            <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
            <tr id="hdRow">
                <td width="20%"><img src="space_age_header.jpg" style="width:250px" ></td>              
                <td width="30%" align="center">Sample File</td>
                <td width="30%" align="left">Marimuthu<br>User Code : 179865420</td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            </div>
            <div id="pdf_container" >


            <table border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
            <tr align="center" bgcolor="pink" style="color:#FFF"><td colspan="3"><b>Your Statement Summery</b></td> </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#006" style="color:#FFF"><td colspan="3" align="left">Your Heading.</td></tr>
            </table>
            <table> 
            <tr> <td> Subject </td><td> Code </td><td>Total </td><td>Grade </td> </tr>
            <?php do { ?>
            <tr> <td> <?php echo $row_record['subject']; ?> </td><td>  <?php echo $row_record['code']; ?> </td><td>250 </td><td>A </td> </tr>       

             <?php } while ($row_record = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_record)); ?>    
             </table>
            </div></body></html>
```

Now this is where i am stuck. How do i implement this. How do i return the dynamically generated code back to the

> $pdf_content='

and make it work.

> $pdf_content= include('page.pp'); //something like this doesn't seem to work

I welcome any alternative idea on the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing to note about your code changes is that the HTML is now outside of a code block. This means that PHP will send that code to the browser as it's processed. To get around this you would need to enable output buffering to capture the rendered text.

```
ob_start();
include('page.php');
$pdf_content = ob_get_clean();
ob_end_clean();
```

Note that some systems may limit the size of the output buffer (see the [output_buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php#ini.output-buffering) setting). You can check that using `ini_get('output_buffering');`. If a limit is enabled make sure the size of your rendered HTML is less than the maximum size of the buffer.